# MongoDB mapreduce missing data with 'null' in return

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

So this is strange. I'm trying to use mapreduce to group datetime/metrics under a unique port:

Document layout:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5069d68700a2934015000000"),
        "port_name" : "CL1-A",
        "metric" : "340.0",
        "port_number" : "0",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2012-09-30T13:44:00Z"),
        "array_serial" : "12345"
}
```

and mapreduce functions:

```
var query = {
        'array_serial' : array,
        'port_name' : { $in : ports },
        'datetime' : { $gte : from, $lte : to}

    }

    var map = function() {
        emit( { portname : this.port_name } , { datetime : this.datetime,
                                metric : this.metric });
    }

    var reduce = function(key, values) {
        var res = { dates : [], metrics : [], count : 0}

        values.forEach(function(value){
            res.dates.push(value.datetime);
            res.metrics.push(value.metric);
            res.count++;
        })

        return res;
    }

    var command = {
        mapreduce : collection,
        map : map.toString(),
        reduce : reduce.toString(),
        query : query,
        out : { inline : 1 }

    }

    mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(command, function(err, dbres){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(dbres.documents);
        res.json(dbres.documents[0].results);
    })
```

If a small number of records is requested, say 5 or 10, or even 60 I get all the data back I'm expecting. Larger queries return truncated values....

---

I just did some more testing and it seems like it's limiting the record output to 100?
This is minutely data and when I run a query for a 24 hour period I would expect 1440 records back... I just ran it a received 80. :\

Is this expected? I'm not specifying a limit anywhere I can tell...

---

More data:

Query for records from 2012-10-01T23:00 - 2012-10-02T00:39 (100 minutes) returns correctly:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "portname": "CL1-A"
    },
    "value": {
      "dates": [
        "2012-10-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "2012-10-01T23:01:00.000Z",
        "2012-10-01T23:02:00.000Z",
         ...cut...
        "2012-10-02T00:37:00.000Z",
        "2012-10-02T00:38:00.000Z",
        "2012-10-02T00:39:00.000Z"
      ],
      "metrics": [
        "1596.0",
        "1562.0",
        "1445.0",
        ...cut...
        "774.0",
        "493.0",
        "342.0"
      ],
      "count": 100
    }
  }
]
```

...add one more minute to the query 2012-10-01T23:00 - 2012-10-02T00:39 (101 minutes) :

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "portname": "CL1-A"
    },
    "value": {
      "dates": [
        null,
        "2012-10-02T00:40:00.000Z"
      ],
      "metrics": [
        null,
        "487.0"
      ],
      "count": 2
    }
  }
]
```

the `dbres.documents` object shows the correct expected emitted records:

```
[ { results: [ [Object] ],
    timeMillis: 8,
    counts: { input: 101, emit: 101, reduce: 2, output: 1 },
    ok: 1 } ]
```

...so is the data getting lost somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rule number one of MapReduce:

**Thou shall return from Reduce the exact same format that you emit with your key in Map.**

Rule number two of MapReduce:

**Thou shall reduce the array of values passed to reduce as many times as necessary.  Reduce function may be called many times.**

You've broken both of those rules in your implementation of reduce.

Your Map function is emitting key, value pairs.

key: port name  (you should simply emit the name as the key, not a document)
value: a document representing three things you need to accumulate (date, metric, count)

Try this instead:

```
map = function() {  // if you want to reduce to an array you have to emit arrays
    emit ( this.port_name, { dates : [this.datetime], metrics : [this.metric], count: 1 });
}

reduce = function(key, values) {        // for each key you get an array of values
   var res = { dates: [], metrics: [], count: 0 };  // you must reduce them to one

   values.forEach(function(value) {
            res.dates = value.dates.concat(res.dates);
            res.metrics = value.metrics.concat(res.metrics);
            res.count += value.count;   // VERY IMPORTANT reduce result may be re-reduced
        }) 

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to output the map reduce data in a temp collection instead of in memory. May that is the reason. From [Mongo Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions):

> { inline : 1} - With this option, no collection will be created, and
>   the whole map-reduce operation will happen in RAM. Also, the results
>   of the map-reduce will be returned within the result object. Note that
>   this option is possible only when the result set fits within the 16MB
>   limit of a single document. In v2.0, this is your only available
>   option on a replica set secondary.

Also, It may not be the reason but MongoDB has data size limitations (2GB) on a 32bit machine.

Comment: Good suggestion, I just tried it, and am still getting truncated data. The truncated collections have "null" as the first value of the metric and dates arrays, I'm wondering if that's a clue.

Comment: Oh, and the output of a query with 4 ports is only 6k, so I'm not really getting close to the 16mb limit.

Comment: oh, then can you please paste the mongodump of data on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something like that.

Comment: it's definitely a clue - see my answer - your map and reduce formats are inconsistent. Data limits don't have anything to do with your problem.